# Create struct array by a function C++

Tags: c++, pointers, structure, heap-memory, stack-memory

I want to create a function that creates an array of structures. What I have done is the following:

```
struct Student {
    char studentNames[128]; 
    unsigned int FN; 
    short selectiveDisciplinesList[10]; 
    unsigned short countOfSelectiveDisciplines; 
    bool hasTakenExams;
};
    
void fillInStudentInfo(Student &student) {...}

Student createStudentsArray() {
    unsigned int countOfStudents;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of students You are going to write down: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> countOfStudents;
    Student studentsArray[countOfStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfStudents; ++i) {
        fillInStudentInfo(studentsArray[i]);
    }

    return *studentsArray;
}
```

However, when in `main()`, I assign:

```
Student studentArray = createStudentsArray();
```

I can not access the members of each different struct (f.e. `studentArray[i].something`).

Where does the issue come from?

If I do it like this:

```
Student * createStudentsArray() {
    ...
    return studentsArray;
}
```

with

```
Student * studentArray = createStudentsArray();
```

My IDE warns me:

> Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned

But I do seem to be able to access the members of each struct. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: please please use std::vector, this is what its for

Comment: On how and why you can return `studentsArray` and observe it seeming to work: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really cannot do what you are trying to do in that way:

```
Student createStudentsArray() {
    ...
    Student studentsArray[countOfStudents];
    ...
    return *studentsArray;
}
```

Firstly, this is using a variable length array, which strictly speaking is [invalid C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/). My compiler, for example, doesn't allow it.

Second, it will only return one `Student`. Even if it returned them all, its very inefficient because it would have to copy them all, but it doesn't.

You tried this:

```
Student *createStudentsArray() {
    ...
    Student studentsArray[countOfStudents];
    ...
    return studentsArray;
}
```

This is even worse. The memory allocated to that array is released once the function ends. This is what the compiler warned you about. Things seemed to work afterwards, but Very Bad Things(tm) will happen very soon afterwards.

Most experienced C++ devs will do this:

```
std::vector<Student> createStudentsArray() {
    ...
    std::vector<Student> students(countOfStudents);
    ...
    return students;
}
```

If you "are not allowed to use vector" (StackOverflow sees that all the time), then do:

```
Student *createStudentsArray() {
    ...
    Student *studentsArray = new Student[countOfStudents];
    ...
    return studentsArray;
}
```

But you must then `delete[]` that array once you are finished using it.

Footnote - for extra info, if you are really interested.

In fact, the experienced devs would do this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student>> createStudentsArray() {
    ...
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Student> students(countOfStudents);
    for (int......)
    {
        students.push_back(std::make_shared<Student>());
        ...
    }
    return students;
}
```

Now, the `vector` contains a bunch of smart pointers rather than the actual objects, that is the most efficient way to make arrays (or other containers) of largish objects. `std::vector` and `std::shared_ptr` will clean up all the memory for you automatically.

Comment: I dunno about the `shared_ptr` riff. I've picked up a somewhat pathological hatred of them used for anything other than shared ownership.

Comment: I don't know anyone who would use `vector<shared_ptr<Student>` over `vector<Student>` in this kind of situation, unless `Student` was a polymorphic base class. And even then, `std::unique_ptr` would almost always be preferred over `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: You got the point about 'not being allowed to use vectors' correct haha. Still haven't got to use them. Using 'new' for dynamic array actually makes lots of sense - it's the same for any other int/char/etc array. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @RemyLebeau In this situation yes, since the size is known in advance and very little fiddling about is done. But once you start doing things that require moving things around or if the possibility exists of moving things around then this.. So this is my standard pattern for all large scale shipping c++ code. Maybe unique_ptr instead tho.